# How to create one Model (table) for each user on django?

Tags: django

I have a Model, and want every User of the system has a table reserved for himself, respecting this Model.

To make it clear:

Imagine the Model "Games".
I do not want that there is only one table "games", but there is:
foo_games, bar_games (foo / bar are users of the system)

How to do this ?

---

edit:

why ?

Imagine I have 1000 users, and each User has 100 games.

Do you think you have a table with 1000 * 100 items is better than having 1000 tables with 100 items each?

Comment: You may want to rethink your problem.  Separate tables per user shouldn't be necessary.  One table of "games" should work with a Foreign Key to the User table.

Comment: Exactly. Have a User model where one of the properties is a reference to the Games model.

Comment: Answer to your question "Do you think you have a table with 1000 * 100 items is better than having 1000 tables with 100 items each?": YES. Absolutely, definitely, no question.

Answer (score 14):

The way this is typically handled in with the Django ORM is by linking the two models together (tables) with a Foreign Key.  You can then get just the records that apply to a user by using the .filter() method.  In this way it will seem like each user has their own table.  For example...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The ForeignKey field here provides a "link" that relates 1 Game record to a specific User.

When you want to retrieve the Games that apply just to 1 user, you can do so like this:

```
# Select whichever user you want to (any of these work)
user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
user = User.objects.get(id=64)
user = request.user

# Then filter by that user
user_games = Game.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

**Edit --**

To answer your question about more rows vs. more tables:  Relational database servers are optimized to have a huge row capacity within a single table.  With your example query, 1000 * 100 is only 100,000 records, which is probably only 0.01% of what a table can theoretically hold (server memory and storage aside).

Comment: that's right, but I'd make owner a ManyToMany field, that way same game could be shared by many users

Comment: Based on the OP's description of "one table per user" I was assuming there would never be that occurrence.  Depending on the application though there certainly could be.