# Django, each user having their own table of a model

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models

A little background. I've been developing the core code of an application in python, and now I want to implement it as a website for the user, so I've been learning Django and have come across a problem and not sure where to go with it. I also have little experience dealing with databases

Each user would be able to populate their own list, each with the same attributes. What seems to be the solution is to create a single model defining the attributes etc..., and then the user save records to this, and at the same time very frequently changing the values of the attributes of the records they have added (maybe every 5~10 seconds or so), using filters to filter down to their user ID. Each user would add on average 4000 records to this model, so say just for 1000 users, this table would have 4 million rows, 10,000 users we get 40million rows. To me this seems it would impact the speed of content delivery a lot?

To me a faster solution would be to define the model, and then for each user to have their own instance of this table of 4000ish records. From what I'm learning this would use more memory and disk-space, but I'd rather get a faster user experience as my primary end point.

Is it just my thinking because I don't have experience with databases? Or are my concerns warranted and I should find a solution as to how to be able to do the latter?
This post asked the same question I believe, but no solution on how to achieve it. [How to create one Model (table) for each user on django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765186/how-to-create-one-model-table-for-each-user-on-django)

Comment: 40 million rows in and of itself isn't necessarily a performance issue waiting to happen.  What database backend are you using?  What is the size of an average row?  How many/what type of indexes are present?

Comment: I was going to use sqlite, I've heard it was fastest. Each row contains 11 columns, 6 of which are binary, 3 short strings and 2 numerical. The indexes I wanted would be user (if there is just one gigantic table) and one of the columns which is binary. So you think I'm worrying about a problem that doesn't exist? This is my first website I am writing so I wanted something that would scale well if in the future if there are lots of users, if one table would suffice with that many records then I'm happy to implement it that way.