# Single table vs Table per user

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I am creating backend for a messaging application. I want it to be mostly a web app so would have to store the list of people with whom a user chats and all the messages in the server. However, I also wanted to have the ability to extend it and use the same backend for a mobile app. So I was thinking of having a separate database or table for every user and only open the connection to it when a user connects to the backend using WebSocket. However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765186/how-to-create-one-model-table-for-each-user-on-django) post, it seems that in most cases, it is better to have a single table and have many to one relation. So what would be the best choice in my usage? Also, how can I go about implementing that in Django?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Despite that, it is too broad. PS Your last question is too broad. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please ask one question per post.

Comment: There is nothing in your "requirements" that lets one choose--and no matter how you edit them there isn't going to be--until you have done research, investigation & estimation--and then you wouldn't need us--and even then you wouldn't know the correct answer for sure without actual multiple implementation & measurement. This sort of question is just too broad. You need to learn & summarize your needs, options & your cost/benefit, not ask us to.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find a solution.